# iOS App is not showing new version of new build

Tags: ios, app-store

I have uploaded an iOS app on iTunes Connect and it's updated on iTunes Connect account. But it is not showing new version of build in the App Store.
Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Answer (score 0):

It will take sometime for the App update to be available on App store, even-though it is shown "Ready for Sale" in iTunes connect. 
    I have submitted an update of my App last week and after the status of the app changes to "Ready for sale" in iTunes, it took about 1 hour to show the update on App store.